# Regarding $S^3$ as the set of all quaternions of modulus $1$

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to answer a question that asks me to regard $S^3$ as the set of all quaternions of modulus $1$. What does this actually mean?

Thanks

Comment: A quaternion $a + bi + cj + dk$ has norm $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2$. The quaternions of norm $1$ can therefore be identified with $S^3$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Ok, thanks. How would I see that there's a subgroup of the group of homeomorphisms of $S^3$ isomorphic to $Q_8$? I can see an obvious action of $Q_8$ on $S^3$ using this identification, but how do I show the action is continuous?

Comment: Multiplication by any quaternion is continuous; in fact it can be described by polynomial functions, which are clearly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the comments:

> A quaternion $a+bi+cj+dk$ has norm $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$. The quaternions of norm $1$ can therefore be identified with $S^3$.
>
> Multiplication by any quaternion is continuous; in fact it can be described by polynomial functions, which are clearly continuous.

– Qiaochu Yuan May 24 '12

---

There are other questions and answers along these lines:

- [How can one intuitively think about quaternions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/7187/79365)
- [Quaternions and Rotations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/177064/79365)
- [Quaternions as group of rotation and scaling](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/257695/79365)
- [Antipodal map - is there a different homotopy with Lie group structure?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/406279/79365)