# Antipodal map - is there a different homotopy with Lie group structure?

Tags: general-topology

The *antipodal map* $a: S^k \rightarrow S^k$ sends $x \in S^k \subset R^{k+1}$ to $-x$.

It is apparent that $a: S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ is homotopic to the identity map by

$$f_t = \left(\begin{matrix}
\cos \pi t & -\sin \pi t\\ 
\sin \pi t & \cos \pi t
\end{matrix}\right).$$

And this can be easily generalized to $2k+1$ dimensional.

However, for $a: S^3 \rightarrow S^3$, is there a different homotopy with Lie group structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "homotopy with Lie group structure"?

Comment: Hi @PaulVanKoughnett - sorry about the ambiguity. I mean to use a Lie group structure to construct a homotopy. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. First, recall that the group structure of $S^1$ comes from it being the set of unit complex numbers. The multiplication by $e^{it}$, $0\le t\le \pi$, furnishes the desired homotopy.

The group structure of $S^3$ comes from thinking it being the set of unit *quaternions*. The multiplication by $e^{it}$, $0\le t\le \pi$, furnishes the desired homotopy again. The field of complex numbers naturally sits inside of the skewed field of quaternions, since we can identify the complex $i$ with the quaternionic $i$ (or $j$, or $k$).

Comment: Thank you very much! This is the same homotopy in $S^3$ right? Since it is still rotation, just different representation. Thanks!

Comment: @MathSnail I think you get 3 different homotopies by choosing different embeddings of $\mathbb C$ into quaternions. But they all proceed by rotation, since this is how the group acts.

Comment: Thanks - but how can we embed them differently?

Comment: @MathSnail See the last two lines of my answer. (They are not very different)